# What's this Algerian parliamentarian tearing up in his speech in support of Gaza/Palestine?

Tags: parliament, palestine, rhetoric, gaza, algeria

On Oct 31 the Algerian parliament held some symbolic support session for Gaza/Palestine.

[There is](https://www.dzairscoop.com/2023/10/apn-les-groupes-parlementaires-saluent-la-position-immuable-de-lalgerie-sur-la-cause-palestinienne/) a summary in French of what was said.  However, it doesn't explain what is the stuff that a speaker is tearing up at the end of his speech, which can be [seen](https://youtu.be/JecJSa8jgtY?t=317) on (Turkey-based, Yemeni-targeting) Almahriah TV.

> [image]

So, what's he tearing up there? (I don't grok Arabic, in case that's not obvious.)

(In case someone wonders why I [even] looked at that. There was a burst of fake news, apparently originating in Iran that Algeria declared war on Israel in that event.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, from the context, that it's a copy of the [Arab Peace Initiative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_Peace_Initiative). The representative is Sliman Zerkani, and a video of his speech may be found [on his Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/zekanisliman/videos/1012900653126133). As he's ripping up the paper, he says something like:

> We strongly demand as representatives of the people, support for the Palestinian cause as befits the status of Algeria and its historical positions. To withdraw from the false Arab Peace Initiative. It is an initiative which legitimises Arab normalization.